# Nginx returns 400 Connection Reset Error When json body contain a specific value "Halt"

Tags: nginx

When sending a POST method request to the node.js server through the nginx as reverse proxy,

If a JSON body with a specific value is included in the request, the request does not reach the node.js server and nginx returns a 400 connection reset error.

The specific value is `"Halt`.

If the value of any key starts with "Halt, a 400 connection reset error is returned by nginx.

The same thing happens even if I extremely shorten the body and transmit the following data.

```
{
    "name": "Halt Test"
}
```

OR

```
{
    "name": "Halt"
}
```

I checked the nginx debug log, and it seems like a problem occurs when reading the request header.

Below is the debug log.

```
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 http keepalive handler
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 malloc: 00005611B8BFFEE0:1024
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 SSL_read: 62
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 SSL_read: -1
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 SSL_get_error: 2
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 reusable connection: 0
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 posix_memalign: 00005611B81577A0:4096 @16
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 event timer del: 14: 51481711484
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 http process request line
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 http request line: "POST /secret/foo/bar HTTP/1.1"
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 http uri: "/secret/foo/bar"
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 http args: ""
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 http exten: ""
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 posix_memalign: 00005611B826A0D0:4096 @16
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 http process request header line
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 event timer add: 14: 60000:51481724396
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 http empty handler
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 http process request header line
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 SSL_read: -1
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 SSL_get_error: 5
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 peer shutdown SSL cleanly
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [info] 690745#690745: *1459 client prematurely closed connection while reading client request headers, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: secret.foo, request: "POST /secret/foo/bar HTTP/1.1"
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 http finalize request: 400, "/secret/foo/bar?" a:1, c:1
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 http terminate request count:1
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 http terminate cleanup count:1 blk:0
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 http request count:1 blk:0
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 http close request
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 http log handler
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 geoip2 http log handler
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 free: 00005611B81577A0, unused: 512
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 free: 00005611B826A0D0, unused: 3104
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 close http connection: 14
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 SSL_shutdown: 1
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 event timer del: 14: 51481724396
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 reusable connection: 0
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 free: 00005611B8BFFEE0
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 free: 0000000000000000
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 free: 00005611B8BFFCD0, unused: 0
2024/02/20 13:28:45 [debug] 690745#690745: *1459 free: 00005611B8C29910, unused: 384
```

If the body does not contains "Halt", it operates normally.

please help me.

I tried changing json structure and keys but still including "Halt", but still the same thing happened when including "Halt".

I tried disconnecting nginx and node.js servers. But still the same thing happened.

Comment: please add the post request detail you make.